# Sending Data using Python

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I Have a Python application which analyses data from multiple sources in real time. Once the data is analyzed the result of the analysis is stored in a database along with a time-stamp of when it was analyzed.

I would like to access the most recent result of this program remotely from another computer.

I was thinking about using python sockets and having a server script running on the main computer which runs the application and then that way I can access the data using a client script on another computer.

Is there a better way of doing this? Or are there any other solutions out there that can address this need?

Comment: If you trust the client, fetching the information directly from your RDBMS with SQL would probably be easiest. Any reason why you can't do that?

Comment: I should have probably expanded on this in the question, not all data is in SQL some unstructured data is also held in a MongoDB database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end Redis was the best solution. Considering the original question The goal was to be able to send data in real time from one computer to another. Solutions such as Redis or RabbitMQ successfully accomplish this.

With Redis a server can be setup and it can publish messages to the network, clients can then subscribe to data channels and receive the messages in a queue

This Python library was used as a python Redis client :

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad.

Most DB servers will provide a method/API to access the data remotely. You can use Python as a client if there is a DBAPI module for your DB that supports remote access over the network. For example if you are using Postgres you could use the `psycopg2` module.

If you are using a simple DB such as SQLite then you might be able to use an ODBC driver. Some alternatives are [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteNetwork).

**Edit**

`mongodb` provides an API, [`pymongo`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo/).